# VS 2015 configure SFML

Tags: visual-studio, sfml

I have installed VS 2015 Enterprise. I want to prepare a project for SFML

[Tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-vc.php)

But in my version of VS I don't have got C/C++

[My VS](http://prntscr.com/d3s56c)

What can I do to add these directories?

Comment: What about... installing it... by clicking "install" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need at add a C++ file to the project, only then will the C/C++ option appear.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a new C/C++ project inside the solution `File->New->Project` and select `Visual C++` option.

Then you can add the library files, but I recommend you to install SFML via NuGet package manager because it's much easier for beginners